# Using Hibernate Criteria to get entries from with NULL entries in the last

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve the rows in a db using hibernate criteria.
I want to get entries with null values for column in the end using **Hibernate Criteria**. 
For example, if the entries are appearing in the DB as follows for column:

```
Column
______
"AB" 
NULL  
"DC"
NULL
"DG"
```

Then after using Hibernate criteria I should get:

```
Column
_____
"AB" 
"DC"
"DG"
NULL
NULL
```

Is there any way or workaround to achieve this? I am newbie to hibernate. Any help will be appreciable.

---

1. `Heading`

   ## #

Answer (score 2):

You can use order by to sort the entries based on the value.

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(FIELD_NAME));
```

Comment: I was thinking of using this. But will it always return NULL values in the end? I was checking this.. https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-465.

Comment: it should depend on the order, asc or desc? give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 7 year old (!) **unresolved** issue: [HHH-465: order by nulls first / last](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-465).

54 people voting and my favourite comment:

> Emmanuel Bernard added a comment - 08/Sep/06 11:07 AM
>
> "We are working on a large project using Hibernate, and really would like to see this issue fixed."
>
> So either provide a patch or consider commercial support

Answer (score 0):

The optional "nulls first" or "nulls last" may do the trick.
For example:-
Select foo from Foo foo 
order by foo.id asc, foo.field2 desc nulls first, foo.field3

The optional nulls first or nulls last indicate precedence of null values while sorting.

Please check the following link
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: Please don't only post link answers. Just put the essential parts in your answer